# Info.plist must contain the 'CFBundleIcons.CFBundlePrimaryIcon' key

Tags: xcode, tvos

I am trying to upload a `TVOS` app to the `Apple Store`. I have done this several times with no issues. Now when I upload I get an error saying

> Missing `Info.plist` Key. Your app's Info.plist must contain the `CFBundleIcons.CFBundlePrimaryIcon` key.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I restarted XCode and it kept happening. I restarted the computer and the error went away. Leaving this in case it happens to someone else.